# Project using RavenDB builds very slowly. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ravendb

I am working on a new open source CMS built in asp.net mvc 4.  Kind of a personal project mostly to improve my skills and also trying to learn RavenDB.  I initially started building it using EF Code first and Sql compact edition.  Then I started learning about RavenDB so I jumped right in and have been reworking the data store to RavenDB.  However, I am noticing that as I get more and more into it, my Solution and projects take longer and longer to build in Visual Studio, and even longer and longer to run on the initial website startup.  This was not the case when using EF and SQL CE.  I know there is a big hit on application start to load a new document store and create the indexes, but as I am adding more indexes it seems to be taking longer and longer, and I don't understand how this would slow down the actual building of the solution files.  I am thinking maybe I am doing something wrong here.  I am using asp.net mvc 4 and RavenDB build 700.

I am wondering if this has to do with my indexes, as it started when I started to add indexes to my project.  Maybe I am creating them wrong or coding them wrong???  Here is my code for when my indexes are created, and a couple of index examples.

```
// Register RavenDB Indexes
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Posts_BySlug).Assembly, Store);
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Posts_ByCategorySlug).Assembly, Store);
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Categories_BySlug).Assembly, Store);
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(PostTypes_BySlug).Assembly, Store);
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Accounts_ByEmail).Assembly, Store);
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Settings_ByName).Assembly, Store);
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Posts_ByParentID).Assembly, Store);
```

Here are a couple of my indexes.  I only have one Map/Reduce right now, the rest just use Maps.

```
public class Posts_ByParentID : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Post>
{
    public Posts_ByParentID()
    {
        Map = posts => from post in posts
                       select new { ParentID = post.ParentID, Status = post.Status };
    }
}


public class PostTypes_BySlug : AbstractIndexCreationTask<PostType>
{
    public PostTypes_BySlug()
    {
        Map = postTypes => from postType in postTypes
                           select new { Slug = postType.Slug };
    }
}
```

Pretty basic indexes so far as you can see.  I only have 9 so far.  After the project loads, I am running anywhere mostly 1 query per request, and 1-3 on the backend.  Total response times are all sub 1 second.  It's just the initial application start can take up to 45 seconds, and solution build times up to 45 seconds where it used to be like 5 seconds when using EF.  I just don't want it to get worse.  Also I noticed if my site is idle for 5-10 minutes, then when I request a new page it takes another 30-45 seconds to respond.  Any thoughts?

Sorry for the long post.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are all your indexes in separate assemblies? If not then you only need one of those CreateIndexes calls, it searches for all the indexes defined in the passed in assembly and creates them all.

Comment: No, they are all in the same assembly and namespace.  That makes sense, because I did notice when I was running the command line server and viewing the ravendb logs, I could see the indexes being created several times each, but I did not know that it worked that way.  Thanks, I will take the additional calls out.

Comment: Next question would be do you have any custom build steps like razor compilation, or running your unit tests on build?

Comment: I commented out all but one index creation call, and the application_start is WAY faster now.  Thanks for that!  I still have the long solution build times.  I am noticing it is only when I choose "Rebuild Solution" and not when I just do "Build Solution".  I have just been using Build lately, but I used to ALWAYS do a rebuild in the past.  I probably never really needed to though.

Comment: No, no razor or view compilations, and no unit tests are running.  I have not setup any kind of build scripts.  I started with the base MVC 4 web application solution without unit tests and I have not added anything additional to the build process.  If I just do a build it is really fast.  I think I will just stop using rebuild from now on during development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving part answer out of the comment thread. Still not sure about the build times, but in terms of index creation...

You only need one call to CreateIndexes(). You pass it a reference to a whole assembly and it scans for all the indexes contained in the assembly and creates them all.
The code you have posted will be creating every index 7 times.

Comment: Yes, after going through logs again, that is exactly what it was doing.  I changed it to only the first call and it loads up much quickler.  And like I mentioned I am only using "Build" now instead of Rebuild, and is also very quick.  So it seems like my problem is solved for now.  Thanks for the help!!